# Perfect square function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that says 'yes' if the number is a perfect square. Below is the code, please suggest the changes I need to make, considering I am a beginner.

```
def perfsq(x):

    if s == (math.sqrt(x)) and s * s == x:
        print('yes')
```

Comment: what is `s` here?

Comment: 1) `s` is not defined, 2) it's enough to check if `math.sqrt(x)` [is integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help:

```
import math

number = int(input("Enter the Number"))

root = math.sqrt(number)

if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 == number:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: why added 0.5 ?

Comment: In some cases of a large number, the root may not be a perfectly whole number it might be some decimal less and the int() method takes the floor value adding 0.5 to the float number

Comment: incase of a small number, lets say 25, why it is not giving wrong result.  if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 == Number (25):
( 5 + 0.5) ** 2  != 25

Comment: In the case of small numbers like 25, sqrt(25) is 5 and the floor value of 5.5 will be 5. Then 5**2 will again become 25 which is equal to number which we have entered.

Answer (score 1):

example 1:

```
import math

def perfsq(x):
    if math.sqrt(x)%1 == 0:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

call your function:

```
perfsq(16)
```

example 2:

```
x = 16

print('yes') if math.sqrt(x)%1 == 0 else print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

consider this

```
def perfsq(x):
    s = math.sqrt(x)
    p = int(s)
    return p==s
```

Comment: Also, `if whatever: return True else: return False` is just `return whatever`.

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. In this case edit the answer to point out that you are taking the square root and then creating a copy of that value that is effectively truncated by conversion to integer in order to see if the initial result was a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has error since `s` is not defined. Your code should be as follows -

```
def perfsq(x):
    s = math.sqrt(x)          # You didn't define s in your code
    if s == (math.floor(s)):  # Just check if square root is an integer
        print('yes')
        return True
    else :
        print('No')
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 main misunderstandings:

1. The `==` is used to **compare** objects, not to **assign**. I believe you meant to assign `s` with the value of `math.sqrt(x)`. This is done by `s = math.sqrt(x)`.
2. Even with the above change, you can't put that assignment inside the `if` statement. The `if` condition can contain **expressions**, not **statements**. Assignments are statements.

---

To fix that, all you need to do is first assign `s` separatly:

```py
import math

def perfsq(x):
    s = math.sqrt(x) 
    if s * s == x:
        print('yes')
```

Now your problem is that you become dependant on *float precision*. `sqrt` returns a float, so doing operations on floats (such as `s * s`) is risky. As an example, using the above function, running `perfsq(35)` will actually print `'yes'`!!!

To avoid these precision issues, it is enough to check if the square root of a number is an int to begin with. So your code can be greatly simplified to:

```py
import math

def perfsq(x):
    if math.sqrt(x).is_integer():
        print('yes')
```

This is using the [`float.is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method, based on the fact that [`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt) always returns a float.